# Netty read exact number of bytes

Tags: java, netty

I'm extending [`ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html)  and would like to read the exact number of bytes.

```
public class Reader extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
        ByteBuf b = (ByteBuf) msg;
        byte size = b.readByte();
        //Now I want to read exactly size bytes from the channel
        //and then again read the number of bytes and read the bytes...
    }

}
```

The issue is it may happen that we read less then required bytes from [`ByteBuf`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html). How to read more from the [`Channel`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reading you may use `b.readSlice(size)`. 
However, as you mentioned, the buffer may have not enough data yet for your message. So you need to consume data fully before creating the message. For that case, I would recommend you to use built-in `ByteToMessageDecoder` handler. It will handle low-level bytes for you. So with `ByteToMessageDecoder` your code will look like this:

```
class Reader extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        byte size = in.readByte();
        if (in.readableBytes() < size) {
           in.resetReaderIndex();
           return;
        }

        ByteBuf bb = in.readSlice(size);
        //make whatever you want with bb
        Message message = ...; 
        out.add(message);
    }
}
```

So in this example, you read the number of bytes you need to read for the message - `size`. Then you check if your `in` buffer has enough data to consume. If not - you return control to `ByteToMessageDecoder` until it read more. And repeat, until you have enough data to construct your message.

Comment: Actually, yes. Thanks a lot. But what about the differences between `ReplayingDecoder`? When to use which one?

Comment: @St.Antario please have a look at `ReplayingDecoder` javadocs. It has a very good explanation with examples. Briefly - `ReplayingDecoder` does more and you don't need to check `in.readableBytes() < size`. However, the price is - lower performance.

Comment: ReplayingDecoder can help you deal with complex situation of underlying stream data, e.g. data is not enough.  If you don't care too much about performance, it will reduce your code logic complex too much.